# How to convert more than one number into letters?

Tags: python, char

This is my current code, but it only works with one number. I am using Python.

```py
code = input('Code: ')
code = int(code) + 96
letter = chr(code)
print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to do something multiple times, you need a [loop](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).

```py
while True:
    code = input('Code: ')
    code = int(code) + 96
    letter = chr(code)
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can provide several numbers separated by `,`.

```
codes = input('Codes: ')
letters = [chr(int(x)+96) for x in codes.split(',')]
print(''.join(letters))
```

E.g., when you input `19,20,1,3,11,15,22,5,18,6,12,15,23`
the printed result is: `stackoverflow`